useQueries loses the ability to query data in parallel because Next.js requires server component to be async
The app is running by Next.js.
I have a useQueries hook:
    const userQueries = useQueries({
        queries: user.contacts.map((contactId: string) => ({
            queryKey: ['contact', contactId],
            queryFn: () => getUserById(contactId),
        }))
    });

And function 'getUserById' in api.ts file:
export async function getUserById(userId: string) {
    const supabase = createClient();
    let {data} = await supabase
        .from('users')
        .select()
        .eq('id', userId);

    return data && data[0]

}

I found that when I load data this way, it loads sequentially instead of in parallel.
I tried to make the api function non-async so that each request doesn't wait for the previous one, but Next.js forbids doing server actions without the 'async' prefix. Is there a way around this?

Got an answer to that question on Reddit. Apparently next.js server actions execute in serial, not parallel. Therefore problem could be fixed by fetching data using next.js's fetch client from API routes.

For anyone bumping into this, server actions were considered by many a boilerplate-free alternative to tRPC, and not being able to execute them in parallel was far from ideal.
There are even a few (12 months old) issues in Next.js repo regarding this, so it's obviously a known pain-point for many people.
Well, it turns out you can actually invoke them in parallel, have a look at the repo here: https://github.com/icflorescu/next-server-actions-parallel
